# FFMPEG - ffmpeg image zoom-in according to duration

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg image zoom-in according to length of video for example, if i set length of video for two minutes. than it should continuously zoom out for two minutes,

i have already zoom-out command but i need this for Zoom-in

> ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='1.5-on/duration*0.2':d=325" -t 30 output.mp4

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done manually. For two minutes, frame count is 3000 (@ the default 25 fps).

Use

```
ffmpeg -i img.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='1+on/3000*0.2':d=3000" -t 120 output.mp4
```

`-loop` shouldn't be used when using zoompan with a single image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not smooth on my side

Comment: That's a limitation of zoompan. See https://superuser.com/a/1112680/114058